# Kafka Mysql CDC to Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I was trying to outsource my `MySql` db changes to kafka topic via `source-connector` and that works. Now I want to send those data to elastic search instance.

To do that, I was following this [Kafka Connect Elasticsearch: Consuming and Indexing with Kafka Connect](https://sematext.com/blog/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-how-to/) and this one [Kafka Connect and Elasticsearch](https://rmoff.net/2019/10/07/kafka-connect-and-elasticsearch/).

For CDC of mysql to kafka, I can see the changes I made in mysql and read it creating a source-connector, but when I create another connector `elasticsearch-sink` connector, `source-connectr` **task.state** shown `Failed`! And hence database changes are not going into ES though index is created there as setup in es-config.properties file.

I have put the jar/s inside kafka-dir where for source-connector's lib worked(to avoid further problem regarding classpath problem).

When creating `elaticsearch-sink-connector` I get this error(though for soure, I have no error, and all libs are in same directory!):

> ERROR Plugin class loader for connector:
>   'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector' was
>   not found. Returning:
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@5cc126dc
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:165)

I am running my connector by this:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/elasticsearch-connect.properties
```

In brief, only one of my connectors task.state remains `RUNNING` at a time

Edit: 
`plugin.path` for connect-standablone.properties file:

```
plugin.path=/media/***/projects/playground/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.4.0, /media/***/projects/playground/kafka/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/target/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.2.0-SNAPSHOT-package/share/java
```

both of them contains the  es-connector jar.Last one added later as but still same

What should I do now?

Comment: What is the setting for `plugin.path`?

Comment: the parent folder path of debezium folder and debezium folder also contains es-connector jar[added later] for which `connector-soruce` works

Comment: Can you share the configuration?

Comment: for which one? connect-standalone.properties  or other?

Comment: Mate, I want to see your `plugin.path`.

Comment: added, please check

Comment: Have you restarted Kafka Connect after adding the jars under the `plugin.path`?

Comment: yes! But no luck !

Comment: You're using the wrong version of elasticsearch connector for your Kafka version. You should be using the 5.4.0 release. Don't use snapshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing work like charm when I just change schema.enable to false

```
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

and added extra `/` after the `plugin.path`  though without `/` it worked for source-connector!

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I have replaced my connector version with 5.4.0 release too as cricket_007 mentioned
**Edit-2:**
I later investigated more and found that, extra `/` issue along with the new key properties mentioned below helped me to get rid of `FAILED` state of connectors(only one connector was RUNNING at a time):

```
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

in connect-standalone.properties file

Thanks

Comment: These properties are only valid for the json converter and have nothing to do with the error you got

Comment: thanks, I forgot that I have replaced the older one with that version too, edited now

Comment: My point is that the plugin path change is the only thing that would fix the error in the question

Comment: I get your point, but somehow, first time I replaced the jar and restarted the connector doesn't help while creating the sink connector gave me error, then I made some changes mentioned in the ans(added an extra slash(!), changed those properties(as was giving some suggestion in error message), and updated jar) and restarted, recreated the sink connector, it worked that way!